# What is wrong with field Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

When I try to import dump SQL to database I get error:

```
ERROR 1067 (42000) at line 470: Invalid default value for 'created_at'
```

The following code illustrates structure of table:

```
CREATE TABLE `siga` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pair` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `from` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `send` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ep` float NOT NULL,
  `tp` float NOT NULL,
  `sl` float NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `closed_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `to` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And inserting row"

```
INSERT INTO `siga` (`id`, `type`, `pair`, `from`, `send`, `ep`, `tp`, `sl`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `date`, `closed_at`, `to`) VALUES
(3, 5, 1, 77, NULL, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, '2016-11-01 15:04:19', '2016-11-02 08:52:22', '2016-11-18 15:04:00', NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: Which version of mysql you are using ?

Comment: The message is self-explanatory - `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` cannot be specified as the Default value.

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d5c7d

Comment: `created_at` should be a `timestamp`, not a `datetime`

Comment: I use `Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.50-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
`

Comment: @MisterPi there is the issue, you can set default to `datetime` as `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` since mysql 5.6, before that the data type has to be `timestamp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's weird that your dump generated this table definition.

A column with a `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` can't have the `DATETIME` data type, it must have the `TIMESTAMP` data type.

So you need this column definition.

```
`created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```